# Problem Parsing Json HTTP request into Pipeline (Groovy)

Tags: java, json, parsing, jenkins, groovy

I have a problem prasing this HTTP request into a Pipeline written in Groovy. I have the following json :

```
{"resultado":"ERROR","descripcion":"The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@3d0d3a07 failed to deserialize json object {\"aplicacion\":\"HELLO_WORLD_APP\",\"thirdParties\":[],\"dependencias\":[],\"api\":[{\"value\":\"/api/example/1.0\",\"description\":\"Servicio de ejemplo\"}],\"componente\":\"_/hello-world-app\",\"tipo\":\"_.APP\",\"version\":\"0.0.12\",\"managementLayer\":[{\"component\":\"example\",\"methods\":[\"foo\"]}],\"routes\":[{\"self\":[{\"route\":\"/hello\",\"exact\":true,\"async\":true}],\"external\":[\"/\"]}],\"almInformation\":{\"buildNumber\":\"60\",\"feedbackCategoryList\":[{\"categoryDescription\":\"Resultados del analisis de la salida\",\"feedbackResult\":[{\"value\":\"OK\",\"id\":\"preparing pipeline environment\"},{\"value\":\"OK\",\"id\":\"checking out from SCM\"},{\"value\":\"OK\",\"id\":\"install dependencies\"}],\"categoryName\":\"analysisresultFeedbacker\"},{\"categoryDescription\":\"Parametros / valores utilizados en la ejecucion del job\",\"feedbackResult\":[{\"value\":\"DEPLOY\",\"id\":\"CI_TYPE\"}],\"categoryName\":\"parametersAndValuesUsedInBuildFeedbacker\"},{\"categoryDescription\":\"Version(es) del maven.xml utilizada(s)\",\"feedbackResult\":[],\"categoryName\":\"pomVersionFeedbacker\"},{\"categoryDescription\":\"Artefactos generados en el proceso de construccion\",\"feedbackResult\":[],\"categoryName\":\"mavenArtifactsFeedbacker\"},{\"categoryDescription\":\"Artefactos subidos a Nexus\",\"feedbackResult\":[],\"categoryName\":\"nexusArtifactsFeedbacker\"}],\"buildResultMessage\":\"SUCCESS\",\"executionDate\":\"2019-08-01 11:30:54 CEST\",\"jobName\":\"_-pipeline-266497\"}} given the type java.util.ArrayList<es.la_.gsa.rest.model._._Request>"}
```

I should extract only the description like:

```
The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@3d0d3a07 failed to deserialize json object
```

but I extracted all. I have used jsonSlurper.parseText(response.content).descripcion.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: But what is your problem?

Comment: I would think you need to select `descripcion` from content?

Comment: I would like extract only: The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@3d0d3a07 failed to deserialize json object